# Number of thread in apache http server

Tags: multithreading, apache2

I am developed Apache http server monitoring tool.
In server-info can get the value which is configured in httpd.conf . 
And the server-status doesn't show more detail about thread.
What I want is to get the real-time value of Apache server.
Is there some way to get the real-time value of Apache server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Apache http server is on linux CentOS.
 In Linux command **ps -o pid,comm,user,thcount -u apache** that command give current thread count.

Comment: # ps -o pid,comm,user,thcount -u apache | wc -l         

---this will give you the count of threads

Comment: You dont know how to use code in your response?